# Estimate density before or after separating into pre-defined bins?

Tags: density-function, density-estimation

I want to estimate the density of positive real item price data so that I can predict expected revenue per transaction given a known service fee schedule. Suppose also that the fee schedule is defined on the basis of binned prices, e.g., 0-100, 100-200, etc. The fee schedule is thus applied to binned prices, but the price is given on an (approximately) continuous scale, to the exact dollar amount. Is it better to estimate the continuous density using, say, the logspline method, then slice that density into the pre-defined bins? Or should I take advantage of the discrete structure of the fee schedule by binning the observed prices, then present a Bayesian estimate of the Dirichlet concentration parameters representing each price bin?

Thank you.